# Multiple inputs from Flask Form (requests.get), only first input is appearing in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm looking to create a very simple web form that takes 3 user inputs (a word and two dates) and returns a result. I have the script working, but only one of the user inputs is properly appearing. The other two (the dates) are always set to the default values - regardless of what I import. I'm currently using request.forms.get() and the keys do not show up.  Attached is my code

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)
num = 'Test'
start = '01-01-2020'
end = '09-01-2020'


@app.route('/') 
def index(): 
    return render_template('index.html') 

@app.route('/square/', methods=['POST']) 
def square(): 
    global num
    global start
    global end
    num = str(request.form.get('number', 'Term'))
    #start = datetime.date(request.form.get('start_date', datetime.now()))
    start = str(request.values.get('start', '2020-01-01'))
    end = str(request.values.get('end', '2020-09-01'))    
    print("------")
    print(num)
    print(start)
    print(end)
    data = {'square': num, 'start':start, 'end':end} 
    data = jsonify(data)
    return data
```

The search term correctly changes with user input, but not the dates. In the below code, when the submit values button is pressed after user input, the two dates and terms should load. The dates and terms load properly for the output section of the front-end, but the dates do not appear on the backend. The html code is attached below:

```
PE html> 
<html lang='en'> 
    <head> 
        <title>Flask App</title> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
            * { 
                font-family: sans-serif; 
            } 
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1>Program</h1> 
        <form method="post" form name="my_form" id="form"> 
            <label for="num">Enter Search Term : </label> 
            <input type="text" id="num" name="number" autofocus autocomplete="off" placeholder="Term">
            <!--- </br>  --->
            <label for="start_date">Enter Start Date: </label> 
            <input type="date" id="start_date" name="start" placeholder="01/01/2020">
            <!--- </br>  --->
            <label for="end_date">Enter End Date: </label> 
            <input type="date" id="end_date" name="end" placeholder="09/01/2020">  
            <button>Submit Values</button> 
        </form>
        <p id="square"></p> 
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script> 
            $('#form').on('submit', function(e){ 
                var number = $('#num').val(); 
                var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
                var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
                e.preventDefault();
                function check() {
                        if(number == "")
                            number = "Test";
                        if(start_date == "")
                            start_date = "01-01-2020";
                    if(end_date == "")
                        end_date = "09-01-2020";
                    }
                check(); 
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/square/', 
                    data: {'number': number},  <!--- this is the error --->
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function(data) { 
                        $('#num').val(''); 
                        $('#square').html('Date Range of ' + start_date + ' to ' + end_date + ' with Term: "' + number + '" loaded! Click the button below.') 
                    },

                }); 
            }); 
        </script> 

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Before I even get on to the form, the `global`s suggest that this is totally broken. _do not_ use them in a webapp

Comment: `<form method="post" form name="my_form" id="form"> ` is not valid HTML (I'm pretty certain). There's a floating `form` in that tag

Comment: @roganjosh technically you can have any attribute inside an html tag even without a value. But the `form` tag has no attribute named `form`, and because `form` is a tag name as well, it might have some undesired effects on where the form element starts

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the HTML for method since you have the method already declared in AJAX. This leaves you with something like this:

```
<form name="my_form" id="form">
```

Use Input buttons instead of buttons:

```
<input type="button" id="submit_form_btn" value="submit">
```

Then, correct the form identifier and change the event in your script:

```
$('#submit_form_btn').on('click', function(e){
```

AJAX data should look like this:

```
data: $('#my_form').serialize()
```

Finally, in flask, you should request form data in this manner:

```
start_date = request.form['start_date']
end_date = request.form['end_date']
```

Montior ensure to monitor your browser console for error from the JS end of you application, you may add `console.log('Submission Successful')` to your success fucntion and `console.log('something went wrong')` for error function.